# how to add 00 before and after sting dynamically android

Tags: android, string, string-formatting

hello i am very frustrated while doing this task anyone please help me

i have a string 12.03, 12:12, 12 etc and i want all time in this format 00:00:00.00 is there any way to covert my string to this format automatically like 12.02 should be written as 00:00:12.02 and 12:12 = 00:12:12.00 and 12 = 12:00:00.00.. actually that's the time i am doing this

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(get_time, ":.");
        while (tokens.hasMoreElements()) {
            time_list.add(tokens.nextToken());


        }
```

splitting string but how to get this string into my desire able format??
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want 00:00:12.02 when input is 12.02 and  00:12:12.00 when input is 12:12? why do you want in . format ? why not in simple HH:mm:ss:SS format.

Comment: 12:12 = 12 min and 12 sec so i want to show it in this format 00:12:12.00

Comment: and why do you want it in . format for milisecond ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tokenized the string then you can do it like this

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
public class DateInAndroid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calendar gregoianDate = new GregorianCalendar();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm:ss:SS");     
        String get_time = "15.03";
        List<String> time_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(get_time, ":.");
        while (tokens.hasMoreElements()) {
            time_list.add(tokens.nextToken());           

        }
        if(get_time.contains(".")){
            gregoianDate.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
            gregoianDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            gregoianDate.set(Calendar.SECOND,Integer.parseInt(time_list.get(0)));
            gregoianDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, Integer.parseInt(time_list.get(1)));
        }
        else if(get_time.contains(":"))
        {
            gregoianDate.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
            gregoianDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.parseInt(time_list.get(0)));
            gregoianDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(time_list.get(1)));
            gregoianDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            gregoianDate.set(Calendar.HOUR,Integer.parseInt(time_list.get(0)));
            gregoianDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            gregoianDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            gregoianDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        }
        System.out.println(sdf.format(gregoianDate.getTime()));
    }

}
```

**Output : 00:00:15:03**

---

Sources : Link 1 [click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Link 2 [click Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)